# No WiFi Adaptor found in Lenovo X1 Carbon Generation 7

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, system-installation, lenovo

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu and I just managed to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS onto my Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen 7 in Dual Boot. From Windows Device Manager, I can see that my WiFi card is `Intel(R) Wireless AC 9650 160MHz`. The problem is that currently, I am not able to connect to WiFi as the WiFi Panel in settings says "No WiFi Adaptor Found". These are the things I have done so far:

1. Disabled Secure Boot
2. Installed the driver for the above wifi card from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html and put it into `/lib/firmware`.

I am also unable to connect to the internet in Ubuntu using Ethernet. I hope someone can provide with me a solution to connect to the internet using my wifi (and optionally with ethernet, but focus on wifi). I am very new to linux, so I do not know what more information you require. If you require any more information from me to assist me better please let me know. TThank you very much for your help.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0030]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
```

Output of `dmesg | grep iwl`:

```
[    2.305197] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.323471] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 43.95eb4e97.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.352746] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x354
[    7.381803] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[    7.381815] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[    7.381820] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device config registers:
[    7.381874] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 02f08086 00100406 02800000 00800000 ea238004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    7.381882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00308086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 000001ff
[    7.381886] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[    7.381925] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 00489004 00000040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    7.381932] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000011 0c040005 00000351 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 001f0040
[    7.381952] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[    7.381980] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    7.381987] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    7.608162] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0x0bad1122]
[    7.620281] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

EDIT:

I ran the steps suggested by @chili555 but it still didn't work. Here is the output of `dmesg | grep iwl` after running your command:

```
[    2.327945] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.339990] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 43.95eb4e97.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.383702] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x354
[    7.633032] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[    7.633042] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[    7.633047] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device config registers:
[    7.633235] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 02f08086 00100406 02800000 00800000 ea238004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    7.633242] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00308086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 000001ff
[    7.633245] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[    7.633282] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 00489004 00000040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    7.633288] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000011 0c040005 00000351 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 001f0040
[    7.633307] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[    7.633330] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    7.633336] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    7.853989] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0x0bad1122]
[    7.866822] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

I know almost nothing about this stuff, but it seems like it is still using firmware version 43 rather than 46.

EDIT 2:

I have added the output of running `sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb`:

```
architkithania@x1cg7:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
[sudo] password for architkithania: 
(Reading database ... 126754 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-firmware_1.183.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.183.2) over (1.183.2) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (1.183.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
architkithania@x1cg7:~/Desktop$
```

Edit 3:

Thank you at @chili555 and @Pilot6 for all your help. Finally, I have decided to use Ubuntu 19.10 and the WiFi works flawlessly in this. This result leads me to believe that the error was in fact being caused by the Linux-Firmware being 43. 19.10 uses Linux Firmware 48 and everything works fine. I believe updating the Linux Firmware using this [link](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.173.12_all.deb) provided by @Pilot6 should in fact make the problem go away on 18.04 but since everything is working fine in 19.10 and the next LTS release is just around the corner, I will stick with 19.10 for now and therefore cannot check whether @Pilot6 solution works for sure. Thanks for all your help. The Ubuntu Community is truly awesome.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command. And also `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @Pilot6 I have added that information. Thanks

Comment: Please post output of `ls /lib/firmware | grep iwl; uname -a`.

Comment: Now don't reboot and run `sudo modprobe -r iwlmvm && sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi`. Wi-Fi should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this bug by updating your system. Connect to the Internet by wire and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

After the process is finished, reboot and Wi-Fi should work.

The `linux-firmware` will be updated to a working version.

If it is difficult to update the system without a wireless connection, then download http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.173.12_all.deb, copy it to your Desktop and run:

```
sudo apt remove linux-firmware
cd "$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)"
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.173.12_all.deb
```

Comment: When I plug an Ethernet cable into my computer nothing happens. I cannot connect to the internet via that way either

Comment: OK. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Please see final edit for a summary of my issue.

Comment: That was the next to suggest. It must be a kernel issue. Instead of using 19.10 you could install the 5.3 kernel to 18.04.

Comment: Yea that may work, but this just seems cleaner to me. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Add some information: 
`5.3.0-28-generic` wlan worked, but sound volume can't change;  

`5.3.0-46-generic` `5.3.0-51-generic` `5.3.0-53-generic` sound wolume ok, but wlan same -110: `loaded firmware version 48.13675109.0 op_mode iwlmvm`

Comment: Unfortuantely, your link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 6):

We see that your system loaded firmware version -43 and it crashed. This bug report suggests that firmware version -46 will rectify the issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1828133

The -46 version is now included in the latest *linux-firmware* package. Please download this package on another computer and transfer it to the Ubuntu computer. http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.183.2_all.deb For convenience, please drag and drop it to the desktop of the Ubuntu computer.

Now open a terminal and do:

```
cd "$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)"
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and show us:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Comment: Not everyone has `~/Desktop` for Desktop. It depends on the language. I suggest another dir.

Comment: I fixed it in your post.

Comment: @chili555 Can I test this in the "Try Ubu tu without installing" or do I need a full install for this to work?

Comment: You can do it either way. But it won't be persistent if you try.

Comment: @Pilot6 I just want to test if everything works. If it does then I will go ahead and do a full install. I had a full install previously but I uninstalled it so now I want to make sure it works before partitioning my drives and doing all that good stuff.

Comment: So go ahead and try. If it doesn't work post the required by @chili555 output to your question.

Comment: @chili555 I ran the command suggest by you but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you download the suggested file. Did the package install?

Comment: The problem that you did a reboot after you installed the firmware. The system lost the changes.

Comment: Instead of rebooting run `sudo modprobe -r iwlmvm && sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi`

Comment: I actually went ahead and did a full ubuntu install so I dont think it lost it changes. I have added the output of running the `dpkg` on the question for your reference

Comment: So reboot then and see.

Comment: @Pilot6 I did reboot. But it still says No Wifi Adaptar

Comment: And still is using the 43 version?

Comment: When i run `dmesg`, I can see it loading firmware version 43

Comment: OK. Then download this file http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.173.12_all.deb. Then run `sudo apt remove linux-firmware` and install this `1.173.12` version of it the same way as you installed the `1.183.2`

Comment: Alternatively you can simply update your system by `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. It will download the firmware among other updates. That should fix the issue.

Comment: I wrote another answer.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Please see my final edit for a summary of my entire issue.

Comment: Unfortuantely, your link appears to be dead.

Comment: @jay.sf Look int that directory and find a the current version.

Comment: @jay.sf This, perhaps: http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.197_all.deb

Comment: Found, thx folks!

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to get wifi working on a clean install of 18.04 on my X1C7 using any combination of the steps above, however this  (copied from here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2400595) did the trick

```
sudo apt install git build-essential
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
make -j4
sudo make install
cd /lib/firmware
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, oem kernel was worked.

```bsh
sudo apt install linux-oem-osp1 linux-firmware
sudo reboot
```

(https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/thinkpad-notebook-p1-gen-2-ubuntu-18-04-support-wireless-no-wifi/td-p/4529460)

Comment: worked for me as well after all other options failed!

Comment: actually `oem-osp1` kernel caused issues with sound and suspend; see my other answer mentioning `backport-iwlwifi`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-15IIL and while installing Ubuntu 18.04 and I got a chunk of problems including this.

1. I suggest do not use Rufus to make the boot-able USB. Just format the pen-drive in FAT32 and copy the mounted ISO files to USB.
2. On boot, press F2 to enter BIOS and disable switchable graphics else USB will not boot.
3. Install Ubuntu and boot the system.
4. Use the following commands to fix WiFi:

```
sudo apt install git build-essential
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
make -j4
sudo make install
cd /lib/firmware
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
```

Comment: This is not a great idea to use backports. It will be broken as soon as HWE moves to another kernel.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD** Since the last kernel update, the package from PPA mentioned below leads to extremely slow uplink, but the `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` from official repos works well now.

```
$ apt-cache policy backport-iwlwifi-dkms
backport-iwlwifi-dkms:
  Installed: 7906-0ubuntu4~18.04.2
  Candidate: 7906-0ubuntu4~18.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 7906-0ubuntu4~18.04.2 500
        500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**Old respose kept for record:**

None of the options above worked for me, but this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1046682/28757) helped (should be equivalent to the `git clone` above, but less error prone).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```