# No WiFi Adaptor found, Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen 7 (version 18.04 & 19.10)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo, thinkpad

UPDATE since my kernel and firmware updates weren't saving on reboot I moved the question to here: ([Terminal commands not saving on reboot. Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen 7, Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201580/terminal-commands-not-saving-on-reboot-lenovo-x1-carbon-gen-7-ubuntu-18-04))

I am having the same issue as this post ([No WiFi Adaptor found in Lenovo X1 Carbon Generation 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189010/no-wifi-adaptor-found-in-lenovo-x1-carbon-generation-7)), however nothing suggested in the post has worked so far. It looks like the solution is to upgrade my firmware from -43 to -46 but I have no idea how to do that. See the output I have posted below.

I originally installed 18.04 LTS on my brand new Lenovo x1 Carbon Gen 7. My WiFi card is Intel(R) Wireless AC 9650 160MHz. Currently I am not able to connect to WiFi, and my WiFi Panel says "No WiFi Adaptor Found". These are the things I have done so far:

- Disabled Secure Boot
- Followed the instructions in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dokG4bCF4GQ)
- Followed the instructions in the top comment of this post ([No WiFi Adaptor found in Lenovo X1 Carbon Generation 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189010/no-wifi-adaptor-found-in-lenovo-x1-carbon-generation-7))
- Upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 as the OP did in this post ([No WiFi Adaptor found in Lenovo X1 Carbon Generation 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189010/no-wifi-adaptor-found-in-lenovo-x1-carbon-generation-7))
- Reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 (my current version)
- Tried installing the driver for my wifi card in /lib/firmware (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html)

Please let me know what I can do to fix this. I have spent the last 3 days trying to troubleshoot this issue and nothing seems to work, I am pretty frustrated.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0030]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
```

Output of `dmesg | grep iwl`

```
    [    2.305197] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.323471] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 43.95eb4e97.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.352746] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x354
[    7.381803] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[    7.381815] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[    7.381820] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device config registers:
[    7.381874] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 02f08086 00100406 02800000 00800000 ea238004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    7.381882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00308086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 000001ff
[    7.381886] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[    7.381925] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 00489004 00000040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    7.381932] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000011 0c040005 00000351 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 001f0040
[    7.381952] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[    7.381980] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    7.381987] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    7.608162] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0x0bad1122]
[    7.620281] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Output of `dmesg | grep iwl` DOES NOT CHANGE after I run

```
cd "$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)"
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

OR

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

EDIT: to those of you who are suggesting this post ([No WiFi Adaptor found in Lenovo X1 Carbon Generation 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189010/no-wifi-adaptor-found-in-lenovo-x1-carbon-generation-7)), none of the solutions work there. I have tried them all. The problem right now seems to be that nothing in terminal is saving on reboot.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103092/discussion-on-question-by-darrenmk-no-wifi-adaptor-found-lenovo-x1-carbon-gen-7).

Answer (score 0):

You can try update kernel-image to 5.5.1 from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/