# sudo apt upgrade executes but has no effect on kernel. (Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen 7, Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade, thinkpad, disk

EDIT 2: After nearly 3 days of troubleshooting and reinstalling Ubuntu I am close to giving up and sending my laptop back. If anyone is looking to buy a new laptop and wants to run Ubuntu on it I would strongly recommend avoiding the Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen 7.

EDIT 1: I don't think this has anything to do with the reboot process per se. After running `sudo apt upgrade` without hitting reboot, it seems I am on the same kernel of 5.0.0-23-generic. So for some reason the kernel won't update. However, after the reboot process, if I run `sudo apt upgrade` after rebooting, it will re-install the same packages again.

OP: I was told on this post ([No WiFi Adaptor found, Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen 7 (version 18.04 & 19.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201390/no-wifi-adaptor-found-lenovo-x1-carbon-gen-7-version-18-04-19-10)) to ask another question on the forum. The original problem I was having was that my WiFi panel said "No WiFi Adapter Found". So it was recommended that I update my kernel with the commands `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and my firmware with (http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.173.12_all.deb) and installing with `sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb`

When I enter these commands to upgrade my kernel and firmware install in the terminal they do not have an effect on the kernel. I tried running them twice and they seem to have installed all required packages, however uname -a still shows I'm on the old kernel of 5.0.0-23-generic. However after reboot I have to install the packages again, as if nothing was installed before. I am definitely not running on a live OS because I can boot up without USB. Also I was installing them on my phone's bluetooth connection which gets disconnected as soon as the install is finished.

Here is what I did in order when I was originally installing: `Power on -> Pressed Enter to disrupt normal startup -> Pressed F12 to enter boot menu -> on boot menu, selectedUSB HDD: SMI USB DISK -> on grub, selected Install Linux`

Comment: Euh was `USB HDD: SMI USB DISK` and `selected Install Linux` during install? otherwise you are on an live OS.

Comment: Yes that was during install. Hold on I am editing my OP.

Comment: is the new kernel in /boot or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `sudo apt upgrade` will update your kernel. I had the same issue with my X1 and solved it by updating the kernel to 5.5.7 manually. If you have access to the internet through cable, try this `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo reboot`. If you don't have Ethernet like me, checkout this link https://askubuntu.com/a/142000. Basically what I did was to download 4 files for the 5.5.7 kernel and put those `.deb` files in my `home` directory. Then I did `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`, and finally reboot.