# No WiFi adapter found Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon 6th gen

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo, iwlwifi

I have been using Ubuntu 18.04 for about a month now on a Dual Boot system. I've had WiFi issues in the past, but nothing that couldn't be fixed by a reboot. However, recently I have not been able to connect to WiFi at all.

On typing `lspci`, I get the following:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V (rev 21)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
06:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
06:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
06:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
07:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
3b:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
```

As you can see, the computer uses Intel WiFi drivers. Sometimes, they don't show up at all with this command.

I've tried all the steps on this answer without much success:
[No WiFi Adaptor found in Lenovo X1 Carbon Generation 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189010/no-widmesg%20%7C%20grep%20iwlfi-adaptor-found-in-lenovo-x1-carbon-generation-7)

I just installed Ubuntu 19.10, hoping the problem would be solved, but that didn't help either. I am currently on 19.10

I am able to connect through USB tethering though, and the WiFi has worked for 5-10 minutes these past few days.

Also, WiFi works just find when I boot into Windows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit 1: Here is the output of `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl`

The output is too long, so here are the opening and ending lines:

```
[    2.780409] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.780412] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.780859] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.77d01142.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.929533] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    2.941530] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.941898] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    2.995866] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 18:1d:ea:c4:e7:f3
[    3.077166] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    3.121398] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.922362] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.056426] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.124598] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   11.996082] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending TIME_EVENT_CMD: time out after 2000ms.
[   11.996085] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Current CMD queue read_ptr 67 write_ptr 68
[   12.013670] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 304 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:2015 iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1f9/0x230 [iwlwifi]
[   12.013671] Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic bnep x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel nls_iso8859_1 kvm irqbypass snd_soc_skl snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core joydev snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_seq_midi snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_seq_midi_event snd_soc_sst_dsp crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul i915 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core mei_hdcp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine iwlmvm intel_rapl_msr ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_intel snd_rawmidi snd_intel_nhlt mac80211 aesni_intel snd_hda_codec uvcvideo btusb libarc4 rmi_smbus btrtl rmi_core thinkpad_acpi snd_hda_core snd_hwdep aes_x86_64 crypto_simd videobuf2_vmalloc nvram drm_kms_helper btbcm cryptd input_leds videobuf2_memops glue_helper btintel videobuf2_v4l2 intel_cstate videobuf2_common serio_raw snd_pcm wmi_bmof bluetooth intel_wmi_thunderbolt snd_seq ledtrig_audio intel_rapl_perf iwlwifi videodev mc drm snd_seq_device processor_thermal_device snd_timer
[   12.013735] RIP: 0010:iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1f9/0x230 [iwlwifi]
[   12.013749]  iwl_write_prph+0x3e/0x90 [iwlwifi]
[   12.013753]  iwl_force_nmi+0x53/0x60 [iwlwifi]
[   12.013758]  iwl_trans_pcie_sync_nmi+0x1f1/0x260 [iwlwifi]
[   12.013763]  iwl_pcie_send_hcmd_sync+0x3ca/0x4b0 [iwlwifi]
[   12.013770]  iwl_trans_pcie_send_hcmd+0x34/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[   12.013775]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x5d/0xc0 [iwlwifi]
[   12.013783]  iwl_mvm_send_cmd+0x34/0x90 [iwlmvm]
[   12.013788]  iwl_mvm_send_cmd_pdu+0x51/0x70 [iwlmvm]
[   12.013795]  iwl_mvm_remove_time_event+0xc9/0xe0 [iwlmvm]
[   12.013800]  iwl_mvm_stop_session_protection+0x5a/0x90 [iwlmvm]
[   12.013805]  iwl_mvm_protect_session+0x127/0x2a0 [iwlmvm]
[   12.013811]  ? iwl_mvm_ref_sync+0x34/0x130 [iwlmvm]
[   12.013816]  iwl_mvm_mac_mgd_prepare_tx+0x64/0x90 [iwlmvm]
[   12.013820]  ? iwl_mvm_mac_mgd_prepare_tx+0x64/0x90 [iwlmvm]
[   12.013887] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
```

Ending:

```
[   17.049253] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   17.049568] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
[   17.100389] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
```

Edit 2: On entering `dmesg | grep 02:00`:

```
[    0.639695] pci 0000:02:00.0: [8086:24fd] type 00 class 0x028000
[    0.639803] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xee200000-0xee201fff 64bit]
[    0.640435] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    2.780409] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.780412] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.780859] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.77d01142.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.929533] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    2.941530] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.941898] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    2.995866] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 18:1d:ea:c4:e7:f3
[    3.121398] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.922362] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.056426] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.124598] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   11.996082] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending TIME_EVENT_CMD: time out after 2000ms.
[   11.996085] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Current CMD queue read_ptr 67 write_ptr 68
[   12.013887] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[   12.013889] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[   12.014080] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: 24fd8086 00100000 02800078 00000000 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   12.014081] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00108086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 00000100
[   12.014083] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000040: 00020010 10008ec0 001b0c10 0045e811 10110000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   12.014084] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000060: 00000000 00080812 00000005 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   12.014086] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000080: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   12.014087] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 000000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   12.014088] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 c823d001 0d000000 00804005 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   12.014089] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 000000e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   12.014091] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000100: 14010001 00100000 00000000 00462031 00003001 00002000 00000014 40000001
[   12.014092] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000120: 0000000f ee200460 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   12.014094] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000140: 14c10003 ffc4e7f3 181deaff 15410018 00000000 0001001e 00481e1f 00000000
[   12.014095] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[   12.014123] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[   12.014124] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[   12.014127] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
[   12.014151] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00100000 00000000 00462031 00003001 00002000 00000014 40000001
[   12.014152] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: 0000000f ee200460 00000000
[   12.014153] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.0) config registers:
[   12.014252] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi root port (0000:00:1c.0) AER cap structure:
[   12.032234] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW error, resetting before reading
[   12.056226] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   12.056228] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000080, count: -1850087776
[   12.056252] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 36.77d01142.0
[   12.056254] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   12.056255] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000048B | trm_hw_status0
[   12.056255] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   12.056256] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC0902620 | branchlink2
[   12.056262] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | interruptlink1
[   12.056265] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000082F | interruptlink2
[   12.056267] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[   12.056270] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000002 | data2
[   12.056272] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[   12.056274] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000246 | beacon time
[   12.056276] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   12.056277] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000246 | tsf hi
[   12.056278] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   12.056279] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFF13 | time gp2
[   12.056281] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | uCode revision type
[   12.056282] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x90AA1A45 | uCode version major
[   12.056283] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | uCode version minor
[   12.056285] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000010 | hw version
[   12.056286] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[   12.056287] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF9D1A | hcmd
[   12.056288] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000018 | isr0
[   12.056290] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   12.056291] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000246 | isr2
[   12.056293] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   12.056295] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC092B51A | isr4
[   12.056296] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | last cmd Id
[   12.056298] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00573978 | wait_event
[   12.056299] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF9D1A | l2p_control
[   12.056301] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000028 | l2p_duration
[   12.056302] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8C42 | l2p_mhvalid
[   12.056304] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x005739F8 | l2p_addr_match
[   12.056305] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF9D1A | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   12.056307] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00573998 | timestamp
[   12.056309] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF9D1A | flow_handler
[   12.074962] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC092B51A | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   12.074964] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | umac branchlink1
[   12.074965] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00573978 | umac branchlink2
[   12.074966] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF9D1A | umac interruptlink1
[   12.074967] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000028 | umac interruptlink2
[   12.074968] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8C42 | umac data1
[   12.074968] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x005739F8 | umac data2
[   12.074969] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF9D1A | umac data3
[   12.074970] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00573998 | umac major
[   12.074971] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF9D1A | umac minor
[   12.074972] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xAEBB2A00 | frame pointer
[   12.074972] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x85429601 | stack pointer
[   12.074973] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xCB0D9E28 | last host cmd
[   12.074974] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8C42 | isr status reg
[   12.093246] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
[   12.093538] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Couldn't send TIME_EVENT_CMD: -5
[   14.789902] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   14.896234] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[   14.896258] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[   14.896259] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[   14.896260] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -5
[   14.896262] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[   14.931951] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW error, resetting before reading
[   14.955891] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   14.955912] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000010, count: 7
[   14.955913] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 36.77d01142.0
[   14.955914] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   14.955915] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x31122B54 | trm_hw_status0
[   14.955915] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000000D | trm_hw_status1
[   14.955916] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC0902620 | branchlink2
[   14.955917] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | interruptlink1
[   14.955918] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000007 | interruptlink2
[   14.955918] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[   14.955919] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000002 | data2
[   14.955920] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[   14.955920] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000246 | beacon time
[   14.955921] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   14.955922] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000246 | tsf hi
[   14.955922] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   14.955923] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFF13 | time gp2
[   14.955924] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | uCode revision type
[   14.955924] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x90AA1A45 | uCode version major
[   14.955925] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | uCode version minor
[   14.955926] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000010 | hw version
[   14.955927] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[   14.955927] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF9D1A | hcmd
[   14.955928] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000018 | isr0
[   14.955929] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   14.955929] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000246 | isr2
[   14.955930] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   14.955931] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00413BD0 | isr4
[   14.955931] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF9D1A | last cmd Id
[   14.955932] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC090517F | wait_event
[   14.955933] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | l2p_control
[   14.955933] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xCAFC0018 | l2p_duration
[   14.955934] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8C42 | l2p_mhvalid
[   14.955935] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xCAFC0018 | l2p_addr_match
[   14.955936] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8C42 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   14.955936] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00A01C30 | timestamp
[   14.955937] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   14.973783] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00413BD0 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   14.973821] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF9D1A | umac branchlink1
[   14.973822] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC090517F | umac branchlink2
[   14.973823] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | umac interruptlink1
[   14.973824] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xCAFC0018 | umac interruptlink2
[   14.973825] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8C42 | umac data1
[   14.973827] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xCAFC0018 | umac data2
[   14.973828] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8C42 | umac data3
[   14.973829] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00A01C30 | umac major
[   14.973831] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac minor
[   14.973833] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFC59A700 | frame pointer
[   14.973834] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x73C73D65 | stack pointer
[   14.973835] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xCB0D9E28 | last host cmd
[   14.973836] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8C42 | isr status reg
[   14.991671] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Firmware error during reconfiguration - reprobe!
[   14.991697] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[   16.836170] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwl_trans_wait_tx_queues_empty bad state = 0
[   17.049253] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   17.049568] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
[   17.100389] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I've added the output! Thanks!

Comment: "PCI issues?" Let's see what's going on on the PCI bus: `dmesg | grep  02:00`

Comment: Edited accordingly! Thanks!