# Wifi adaptor for Lenovo x1

Tags: drivers, wireless, lenovo, 20.04, iwlwifi

I am having a lot trouble with the wifi adaptor for my Lenovo X1. I just updated to Ubuntu 20.04. I had previously been running Ubuntu 18, and was able to address the issue by running:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git build-essential
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi/
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
make -j8
sudo make install
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

That however does not seem to be working in 20.04. I tried following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189010/no-wifi-adaptor-found-in-lenovo-x1-carbon-generation-7) by downloading the ucode file from [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) and running:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo cp ~/Downloads/iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0/iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode
sudo modprobe -r iwlmvm && sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

I have rebooted etc and it is still not working. I see no wifi options in the settings panel. Following the previous suggestions for problem solving here are a few outputs:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
52:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0080]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
53:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.907244] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    3.907245] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8324:9176b151
[    3.931619] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.425083] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:52:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Comment: Do `cd backport-iwlwifi/ && sudo make uninstall` then reboot.  If the kernel iwlwifi module doesn't work, file a bug report as what is happening is not normal

Comment: @Jeremy31 thanks that worked. Not sure why it was failing w the initial install! Oh well.