# WiFi interface disconnected Lenovo X1 Extreme Gen 4 Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, network-manager, 22.04, iwlwifi

I have a brand new Lenovo X1 Extreme Gen4, with Ubuntu preloaded (it was 20.04 I think). Wifi not working and not sure what to do. So I decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 in any case. But still the WiFi was not working at all. So I dig a bit online (see posts below). The hardware seems to be recognized properly but the interface is permanently disconnected.

I look for similar posts in the internet:

- [No WiFi Adaptor found in Lenovo X1 Carbon Generation 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189010/no-wifi-adaptor-found-in-lenovo-x1-carbon-generation-7)
- [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS driver Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210 160MHz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189010/no-wifi-adaptor-found-in-lenovo-x1-carbon-generation-7)
- [Intel Wifi 6 AX210 - WiFi not working after Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-6-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update/1360291#1360291)
- [Got My First Thinkpad - X1 Extreme Gen 4!!](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/qtapr4/got_my_first_thinkpad_x1_extreme_gen_4/) which mention the wifi issue on Ubuntu 20.04, but I don't get the [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-6-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update/1360291#1360291) mentioned in the post

Even try some generic fixes from posts like ["Wi-Fi Not Working in Linux? Here’s How to Fix it"](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-wi-fi-not-working-ubuntu/).

So here my specs and some useful outputs.
Running `sudo lshw -C network` I get:

```bash
 *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlp9s0
       version: 1a
       serial: f0:b6:1e:58:62:ef
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-37-generic firmware=66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.uc latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:ae100000-ae103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 11
       bus info: usb@3:1
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 22:63:bd:8f:bc:25
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.15.0-37-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.117 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

Running `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` I get:

```bash
[   33.607446] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   33.620244] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   33.620263] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.63.2.2
[   33.620558] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded firmware version 66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   33.661199] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[   33.814019] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0x5a8dfca
[   33.825662] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x10d000
[   33.895052] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: base HW address: f0:b6:1e:58:62:ef
[   33.912770] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0 wlp9s0: renamed from wlan0
```

`sudo modprobe iwlwifi` command does not show me anything at all... :/

So I decided to attach my smartphone and do USB tethering to access internet, as you can see running `nmcli`, I get:

```bash
usb0: connected to Wired connection 1
        "Huawei PCT-L29"
        ethernet (rndis_host), 22:63:BD:8F:BC:25, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.42.117/24
        route4 192.168.42.0/24 metric 100
        route4 169.254.0.0/16 metric 1000
        route4 default via 192.168.42.129 metric 100
        inet6 fe80::6e49:8624:8cec:152d/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024

wlp9s0: disconnected
        "Intel 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz"
        wifi (iwlwifi), F0:B6:1E:58:62:EF, hw, mtu 1500

p2p-dev-wlp9s0: disconnected
        "p2p-dev-wlp9s0"
        wifi-p2p, hw

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
        servers: 192.168.42.129
        interface: usb0

Use "nmcli device show" to get complete information about known devices and
"nmcli connection show" to get an overview on active connection profiles.

Consult nmcli(1) and nmcli-examples(7) manual pages for complete usage details.
```

Output of `rfkill`:

```bash
ID TYPE      DEVICE                   SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0                unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth tpacpi_bluetooth_sw unblocked unblocked
 2 wlan      phy0                unblocked unblocked
```

So not sure how to activate the interface and connect to internet... Anybody with more experience can point me where to find the issue?

Thx a lot!

## UPDATE 1: outputs of commands suggested in comments

command `nmcli device wifi list` with usb tethering disconnected:

```bash
IN-USE  BSSID  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
```

command `sudo dmesg | grep wlp`:

```bash
[   11.737388] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0 wlp9s0: renamed from wlan0
```

command `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```bash
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

## UPDATE 2: standing next to router and running `sudo iwlist wlp9s0 scan`

I can see the two network at 2 and 5GHz, but most of the info is Unknown:

```bash
wlp9s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 5C:A6:E6:3B:7C:42
                    Channel:36
                    Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
                    Quality=25/70  Signal level=-85 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"WiFi-3B7C40"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000b4b26f2177
                    Extra: Last beacon: 192ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000B576946692D334237433430
                    IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 074641552024011E28011E2C011E30011E34011E38011E3C011E40011E64011E68011E6C011E70011E74011E84011E88011E8C011E90011E95011E99011E9D011EA1011EA5011E00
                    IE: Unknown: 23021000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 0B050100020000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEF0117FFFFFFFF00000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1624050400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0904000880010000C001
                    IE: Unknown: BF0CB1698B0FAAFF0000AAFF0000
                    IE: Unknown: C005012A000000
                    IE: Unknown: C30402232323
                    IE: Unknown: FF2023090008120010042002C00F438318000C00AAFFAAFF3B1CC7711CC7711CC771
                    IE: Unknown: FF072404000030FCFF
                    IE: Unknown: FF0E260000A40820A408404308603208
                    IE: Unknown: DD0500904C0417
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180201001C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 6C027F00
          Cell 02 - Address: 5C:A6:E6:3B:7C:40
                    Channel:8
                    Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
                    Quality=19/70  Signal level=-91 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"WiFi-3B7C40"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000b4b2f5bda0
                    Extra: Last beacon: 6488ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000B576946692D334237433430
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030108
                    IE: Unknown: 23021600
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 0B050100080000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEF1917FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1608080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080500080000000040
                    IE: Unknown: FF1C23090008120010022002C00F418308000C00FAFFFAFF391CC7711C07
                    IE: Unknown: FF072404000025FCFF
                    IE: Unknown: FF0E260000A40820A408404308603208
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C0418BF0CB179890FFAFF0000FAFF0000C0050008000000C302002F
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180201001C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
```

I run the same command on my other computer located far away from the router, and I get more results (ie the networks of my neighbors), but what is interesting is the values for `Quality` are way highers for my network, like 44/70 for 5.18GHz and 54/70 for the 2.4GHz. Maybe the antenna of my laptop does not work well?

Comment: According to `dmesg` the device is working properly.

Comment: With the USB wireless removed, does the internal device see networks? `nmcli device wifi list` Are there other clues here? `sudo dmesg | grep wlp` or here? `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Comment: yeah exactly! See updates with output of suggested commands

Comment: Please stand right next to your router and run: `sudo iwlist wlp9s0 scan` What is the result?

Comment: thx so much for helping @chili555. Standing next to the router I can see the 2 and 5 GHz networks. Please see output and updates in the main post above. Thx so much again!

Comment: Standing right next to the router, your signal strength is only 25/70. It ought to be 65+/70. I strongly suspect that one or both antenna connections are not firmly snapped into place. I recommend that you discuss this with Lenovo.

Comment: http://www.insidemylaptop.com/images/Asus-K53U-laptop/disassemble-asus-k53u-laptop-24.jpg

Comment: thx so much @chili555!!! Will contact support asap!