No Wi-Fi adapter found ubuntu 20.04 lenovo thinkpad x1 carbon
I have installed ubuntu desktop 20.04 in lenovo thinkpad x1 carbon i7, however the wifi network adaptor is not working showing 'No Wi-Fi' adaptor found', there is also no port to plug a network cable.
By the way its have dual boot, and the wifi card works in in windows. I have disabled Fast Startup in Windows.

This question is similar to: No WiFi Adaptor found in Lenovo X1 Carbon Generation 7. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In future you should be specific with what you installed; you mention Ubuntu and gave a release (20.04), but not which product (Server? Desktop? flavor?) as they install with different kernel defaults, and the kernel stack impacts kernel modules which are commonly called drivers).

@guiverc ubuntu desktop 20.04

@guiverc i tried the answers in the post [link] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189010/no-wifi-adaptor-found-in-lenovo-x1-carbon-generation-7) but it did not work for me

Ubuntu 20.04 is quite old it is possible your wifi is much newer and therefore there is no driveer for it, but to find out you have to include the name and model of your wifi, pls edit your question if you wish to add that info or any other info that might help, do not write it in comments.

@amar please let me know which info you need and i will provide.

You can try with a Live Ubuntu 24.04 session (by booting the iso from USB) and see if your WiFi device is recognized in version 24.04.

to be clear what fedkad meant, was boot into iso and use  Try Ubuntu , may be that is easier, info that is needed is Wifi name and modell.

FedKad and amar thanks , i have upgrade to 24.04 and wifi is working without any issues.
