# Dell Inspiron 3593 shows display unclaimed for Intel Device 8a56 (rev 07)

Tags: drivers, graphics, dell, intel-graphics

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on a Dell Inspiron 3593 (with Intel graphics card), but when I run lshw it shows the display is unclaimed. Unfortunately Dell discontinued their graphics [update tool](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/update-tool), because apparently Linux Kernel should already have all the drivers necessary. But as you can see apparently, that's not the case with me.

In Gnome, when I go to Settings, Details, Graphics, it says: llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 256 bits).

Here are some outputs:

lshw

```
$ sudo lshw -c display
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:90000000-90ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

lspci

```
$ sudo lspci -nv | sed -n '/VGA/,/^$/p'
00:02.0 0300: 8086:8a56 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: 1028:0979
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
```

All xorg video installs

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep xserver-xorg-video  
xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04        install
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04     install
xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04        install
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04      install
xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04      install
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04    install
xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04        install
xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04     install
xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04       install
xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04     install
```

mesa installations

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep mesa
libegl-mesa0:amd64              install
libegl1-mesa:amd64              install
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64               install
libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64               install
libglapi-mesa:amd64             install
libglu1-mesa:amd64              install
libglx-mesa0:amd64              install
libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64          install
mesa-va-drivers:amd64               install
mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64            install
```

libdrm installations

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep libdrm
libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64                install
libdrm-common                   install
libdrm-dev:amd64                install
libdrm-intel1:amd64             install
libdrm-nouveau2:amd64               install
libdrm-radeon1:amd64                install
libdrm2:amd64                   install
```

libva installations

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep libva
libva-drm2:amd64                install
libva-wayland2:amd64                install
libva-x11-2:amd64               install
libva2:amd64                    install
```

cairo

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep cairo
cairo-5c                    install
libcairo-5c0:amd64              install
libcairo-gobject-perl               install
libcairo-gobject2:amd64             install
libcairo-perl                   install
libcairo-script-interpreter2:amd64      install
libcairo2:amd64                 install
libcairo2-dev:amd64             install
libpangocairo-1.0-0:amd64           install
python3-cairo:amd64             install
python3-gi-cairo                install
```

intel installations

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep intel
intel-microcode                 install
libdrm-intel1:amd64             install
xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04      install
```

i915 driver

```
$ lsmod | grep i915
i915                 1826816  0
drm_kms_helper        180224  1 i915
drm                   483328  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
video                  49152  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915
```

lspci and uname

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'; uname -a
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a56 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0979
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a03 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0979
Linux MyPC 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'; uname -a` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6, I just added that output. Thanks for replying.

Comment: The kernel doesn't support this adapter. You can try the 5.3 kernel by `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge`. Reboot to apply.

Comment: wow.... apparently it worked. After installing and rebooting this new kernel, it shows in the Gnome About "Intel® UHD Graphics (Ice Lake 4x8 GT1)" and lshw doesn't show unclaimed anymore (although it doesn't seem to show anything interesting there. Do you think I can install this same kernel on Mint using the same package? By the way, if you answer the question I can tick as the right answer.

Comment: I know nothing about Mint. If it uses the same kernels, it must work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This grahphics adapter is not supported by the 5.0 Linux kernel.

Install the 5.3 kernel by

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge
```

It should properly detect and support this adapter.

Comment: You are the SAVIOUR, Sir! Thank you