# Enable onboard Bluetooth for Asrock x570 motherboard

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

WiFi worked out of the box with a new install of Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, but I've been unable to enable the onboard BlueTooth module.  I encountered this post suggesting upgrading a backported `iwlwifi`.

https://forum.level1techs.com/t/ubuntu-pop-asrock-taichi-x570-wireless/148728/3

I'm not sure how to do this, or if it's advisable, but I found a related [SO post that discusses it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046589/backport-for-iwlwifi).  I suppose the alternative is to use a more recent version of the Linux kernel?

Comment: You can TRY a more recent kernel easily and without any risk. Create a 19.10 LiveUSB and use the "Try Ubuntu" environment. Try it before you go down the road of backporting.

Comment: Good idea @user535733.  I tried 19.10, but had the same issue.

Comment: I also tried upgrading to 20.04, but had the same issue.  I'm using a cheap $10 bluetooth dongle in the meantime that 20.04 detected no problem.  I doubt it's nearly as good as the onboard module, but it unblocks me for now.