# Ubuntu 18.04: No wifi adapter found

Tags: networking, 18.04, dual-boot, wireless

I bought a new laptop *Lenovo S540* and tried dual booting it with windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. The dual boot went fine and after I updated the Ubuntu system my wifi icon got disappeared from top-right menu and in settings, it shows "No wifi adapter found"
[image]

I already tried some of the methods posted online but none of them worked till now.

> lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

```
    00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

> dmesg | grep iwl

```
[   13.689174] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[   13.689176] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   13.689176] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[   13.689312] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.13675109.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   14.968566] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560, REV=0x354
[   14.975120] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   14.975404] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[   15.997193] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[   15.997299] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   15.997334] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: -288669377
[   15.997335] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 48.13675109.0
[   15.997337] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB71F968D | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   15.997337] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3381040B | trm_hw_status0
[   15.997338] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x96318858 | trm_hw_status1
[   15.997339] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4B7695B8 | branchlink2
[   15.997340] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0EC5D74B | interruptlink1
[   15.997340] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x24F3781B | interruptlink2
[   15.997341] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x45C27942 | data1
[   15.997342] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBED7FD4A | data2
[   15.997342] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xACB7D7AE | data3
[   15.997343] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBBD9DEF8 | beacon time
[   15.997344] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x10005892 | tsf low
[   15.997345] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEBFDFD6E | tsf hi
[   15.997345] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4427F2FF | time gp1
[   15.997346] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBF08186D | time gp2
[   15.997347] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE083784A | uCode revision type
[   15.997348] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7FCEEDBF | uCode version major
[   15.997348] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x194E69AB | uCode version minor
[   15.997349] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEBE01001 | hw version
[   15.997350] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x82AA091E | board version
[   15.997350] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAC414028 | hcmd
[   15.997351] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF9477BC5 | isr0
[   15.997352] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x56D95F01 | isr1
[   15.997353] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA440F2D5 | isr2
[   15.997353] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1676709A | isr3
[   15.997354] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEEE47AF2 | isr4
[   15.997355] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6C57755C | last cmd Id
[   15.997355] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3197F314 | wait_event
[   15.997356] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9898FBC2 | l2p_control
[   15.997357] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5FB6BBA3 | l2p_duration
[   15.997357] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x72BA6AAF | l2p_mhvalid
[   15.997358] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1925B308 | l2p_addr_match
[   15.997359] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF6C84A9D | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   15.997359] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFB58FAE6 | timestamp
[   15.997360] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3D7AF30E | flow_handler
[   15.997392] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   15.997393] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[   15.997393] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x201013F1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   15.997394] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   15.997395] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC008CF5C | umac branchlink2
[   15.997396] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[   15.997396] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   15.997397] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | umac data1
[   15.997398] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | umac data2
[   15.997398] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | umac data3
[   15.997399] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000030 | umac major
[   15.997400] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x13675109 | umac minor
[   15.997401] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005C9C | frame pointer
[   15.997401] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F58 | stack pointer
[   15.997402] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   15.997403] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   15.997419] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   15.997421] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   15.997423] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00260000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   15.997426] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   15.997428] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   15.997430] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x71047F37 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   15.997432] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   15.997435] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   15.997437] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   15.997439] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   15.997443] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   15.997448] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   15.997482] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   15.997510] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5c0f, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[   15.997511] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   15.997513] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[   16.009256] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

> uname -a

```
Linux sandy 5.3.0-62-generic #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 24 16:17:03 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

> dkms status

```
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.3.0-62-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 440.100, 5.3.0-62-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Try to boot with a previous kernel using grub menu.

Comment: It is working in 5.3.0-28-generic

Comment: So boot with the bad kernel and report it as a bug by `ubuntu-bug linux`.

Comment: BTW is iwlwifi-backports installed? Maybe this is the reason. It has to be removed. What does `dkms status` show?

Comment: `bcmwl` is unrelated. It is a Broadcom driver. It can be uninstalled, but it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: I am installing  iwlwifi-backports following [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1046682/897844) will update here once its done

Comment: No,  it is a wrong action. That link is obsolete.

Comment: I think that was right action. The wifi is working now;)

Comment: Well, it installed an older driver instead of the kernel one. It was ulikely it builds with the 5.3, but you seem to be lucky. Anyway it is a bug.

Comment: A patch on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1864509 shows it is likely loading the wrong firmware iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode instead of iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-48.ucode  Since it doesn't work as is, could rename or move the Quz file as Qu