# iwlwifi-backports build is rejected for Lts 20.04 during update of all Kernel 5.4.0 series including today

Tags: kernel, iwlwifi

dkms returns Error!  The /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/8324/5.4.0-113-generic/x86_64/dkms.conf for module backport-iwlwifi includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.

I ran the wireless-info script, the dmesg file contains periodic messages every few minutes about the wifi disconnecting and reconnecting. What can I do? I am on a Lenovo W510 which was solid as a rock under 18.04 LTS.

Comment: "the wifi disconnecting and reconnecting" Please check my troubleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Many thanks, Chili555. I checked, and changed REGDOMANS from 00 to US. I also did the temporary update of MTU for wlan0 to 1492. How can I make this a permanent setting on reboot? Will start monitoring dmesg for improvement in wlan0 resets

Comment: backport-iwlwifi-dkms (8324) is too old for your kernel on 20.04. You need to use a newer version. However, without this backport, if the wireless was recognized and working (disconnects or not), then you don't need this backport anyway.

Comment: MTU=1492 is only if you have DSL.

Comment: Install `WiFi Analyzer` on your smartphone, and see what channel usage is in your area, then check your channel setting in your router, and change to a less used channel (1, 6, 11) if necessary to get a reliable connection.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

Nope for kerneltree 5.4 or newer it is not building.

```
apt changelog backport-iwlwifi-dkms

backport-iwlwifi-dkms (8324-0ubuntu3~20.04.4) focal; urgency=medium

  * Disable build against kernel newer than v5.4. (LP: #1932158)
```

but in the universe repo there is an older version which is building (tested it with

```
 dkms status
backport-iwlwifi, 8324, 5.4.0-110-generic, x86_64: installed
backport-iwlwifi, 8324, 5.4.0-113-generic, x86_64: installed
```

)

```
sudo apt install --reinstall backport-iwlwifi-dkms=8324-0ubuntu1
```

Note I do not know if it is fixing your disconnect problem, this is only a workaround for failing building.

Comment: I did check this on my system. and I can confirm that 8324-0ubuntu1 does build under DKMS. I have to wonder why anyone would want to block it building corectly?

Comment: @Karl It won't build against newer kernels, without getting a newer version of backports. Edit your question and show me `dkms status`.

Answer (score 0):

I had my ubuntu 20.04 installed with Kernel 5.15.0-27.29 and everything worked fine. When `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` was given, I noticed the following error message
`The /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/8324/5.15.0-56-generic/x86_64/dkms.conf for module backport-iwlwifi includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.`

This time it was trying to install Kernel 5.15.0-56.62. Then, the Wi-Fi was not getting detected.

I followed the solution given in `https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046589/backport-for-iwlwifi` and it worked. I am just reproducing the steps.

```
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
make -j4
sudo make install
```

Though it generated few errors, warnings,Wifi started working again after a reboot.